# How can I use Flex RemoteObjects with NodeJS?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, node.js, apache-flex, zend-amf

I have a application builded in Flex/AS3, and I use a server LAMP as a proxy/gateway.
I use ZendAMF to make the conversation between Flex <=> PHP.

Now I need to build another server (proxy/gateway) in NodeJS, but the librarys are very very very poor (https://github.com/jamesward/JSAMF, https://github.com/timwhitlock/node-amf, https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-amf), because they dont support RemoteObjects, only NetConnection.

Someone knows any library or already did something between Flex/AS3 and NodeJS, or can shine my path to build something to do this?

Comment: You may be better off using REST, possibly with JSON when communicating w/ NodeJS.  Based on a quick code review of the Flex Framework; it appears that RemoteObject uses AMFChannel which extends NetConnectionChannel which uses a NetConnection.